# Why is Emacs hanging or seeming like it isin an infinite loop?

Tags: regular-expressions, debugging, font-lock

In my current Emacs major-mode for Tecplot macro development, I have a few functions defined:

```
(defconst tecplot-macro-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table)))
    ;; ' is a string delimiter
    (modify-syntax-entry ?' "\"" table)
    ;; " is a string delimiter too
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\" "\"" table)
    ;; |...| delimits variable names
    (modify-syntax-entry ?| "_" table)
    ;; $!... delimits macro calls
    (modify-syntax-entry ?$ "_" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?! "_" table)

    ;; / is punctuation, but # is a comment starter
    (modify-syntax-entry ?# "<" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">" table)
    table))

(defvar tecplot-macro-mode-keywords
  '(("[^#|{! ][[:alpha:]]* =" . font-lock-keyword-face)
    ("$![[:alpha:]]+" . font-lock-function-name-face)
    ("|\\(?:[[:ascii:]]\\|\\s_\\)+|" . font-lock-variable-name-face))
  ;;  )
  "List of keywords for `tecplot-macro-mode'.")

(define-derived-mode tecplot-macro-mode prog-mode "Tecplot"
  "Mode for editing Tecplot macros."
  :syntax-table tecplot-macro-mode-syntax-table
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(tecplot-macro-mode-keywords))
  (font-lock-mode)
  )
```

For some reason, Emacs has begun hanging when I put in the `font-lock-keyword-face` regexp. Why would this cause Emacs to hang? Is there a better way to get the text that the regexp grabs properly type colored?

Comment: If your code, as-is, works fine without the `font-lock-keyword-face` then your reflex is probably too broad

Comment: @nega: I think you mean `regex`.

Comment: Set `debug-on-quit` to `t`, e.g with `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` and run something that causes this delay; then press `C-g` which should give you a backtrace. Edit your question and add the backtrace.

Comment: Unless something in font-lock is constraining it, `"|\\(?:[[:ascii:]]\\|\\s_\\)+|"` would match from the earliest `|` in the buffer all the way to the final `|` in the buffer, unless there were non-ascii (0-127) characters inbetween.  (Or rather not-ascii and *also* not-punctuation syntax... all ascii punctuation would already have been covered, but I guess other unicode punctuation is a consideration.)

Comment: @nickd Indeed. Cursed iPhone autocorrect

Comment: You can try to debug your font-lock keywords using the package font-lock-studio. My guess is that the regex match too much and thus takes too much time to run. An alternative it to match " =" and use code to check that it occurred in the correct context.